# How do I plot neighboring data points against each other on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, random, matlab-figure

I am currently doing an project to improved on the logistic map to create a PRNG.
I am trying to prove that the data generated from my code have correlation among one another when plotted against neighboring data point and try to show it on a graph.

This is my code as shown below. It generates different data point for 500 iterations.

```
    x = rand(1);
    r = 3.99;

    for i = 1:500
    for j = 1:1
    
    X1(i,j) = r*x*(1-x);
    %for next iteration
    x = X1(i,j); 
    
    end
    end

    %output
    disp(X1);
    plot(X1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure if this is what you want to plot but here is `X1` plotted against it's neighbouring values (shifted-self). Every value is plotted as a coordinate pair (`X1[n]`,`X1[n+1]`) where `n` is the index value running from `n=1` to `499`. This results in a curved plot which seems interesting and promising. When indexing I use `end` to specify the last index of vector `X1`.

• `X1(1:end-1)` → From index 1 to 499 
• `X1(2:end)` → From index 2 to 500

Where, `end = numel(X1)` (number of elements) and `length(x1)` in this case.

[image: Output Results Plot]

```
x = rand(1);
r = 3.99;
X1 = zeros(500,1);

for i = 1:500
for j = 1:1

    X1(i,j) = r*x*(1-x);

    %For next iteration%
    x = X1(i,j); 

end
end

disp(X1);
plot(X1(1:end-1),X1(2:end),'.');
title("Plotting Against Neighbouring Value");
xlabel("X1[n]"); ylabel("X1[n+1]");
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I need which is to show that there is a correlation between neighboring points. Thank you so much.